# Require multiple pages for a single bar chart in Crystal Reports 2008

Tags: crystal-reports, crystal-reports-2008

I am creating a bar chart where the values are the maximum of an AVE_ZSCORE field, and this is set as "on change of" a PARTICIPANT_CODE field. On any given occasion, I could have up to 250 records in this chart and therefore I need to split the chart over a number of pages. This number of records is dynamic however, and can range between 150 and 250 records.

I have tried the solution in this thread http://www.tek-tips.com/viewthread.cfm?qid=1257385 and I've followed the instruction as best as I understood (please bear in mind that I'm quite new to Crystal Reports). I created a formula, inserted it in the details section which I then suppressed, then inserted a group on that formula, and inserted the chart in the group footer section. The formula I'm currently using (which I called "chart") to test this out on 4 records is:

WhileReadingRecords;
numbervar cnt := cnt + 1;
if cnt in 1 to 2 then 1 else
if cnt in 3 to 4 then 2

My problem is that the output of this results in 3 graphs of the following instead of 2 graphs containing 2 records each:

1. a group output of 0.00 which has all 4 records (B2, BB, KK, MM) in
   one graph
2. a group output of 1.00 which has only one of the records (BB)
3. a group output of 2.00 which also has only one record, which is the
   same record of the previous graph (BB)

If I change the formula to display as follows:

WhileReadingRecords;
numbervar cnt := cnt + 1;
if cnt in 1 to 4 then 1

Then the output becomes

1. a group output of 0.00 which has all 4 records in one graph (B2, BB,
   KK, MM)
2. a group output of 1.00 which has one record (BB)

So firstly, I don't understand the formula that I'm using or how it works, and secondly I have no idea how to get this working so that I can easily specify the number of columns per chart

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately it's hard to say something without total understanding of your report layout. Some screenshot will easy things alot. As nothing yet specified I expect you have only one (mentioned) group in your report.

To achieve you goal you should render your chart as many times as different group values will be. This is how details section of group is rendered. Not footer or header. As chart can't be added to details section additional dummy group should be created. So in result there will be 2 groups:

- Outer group (*#1*) will be based on your formula field and have no header/footer
- Inner group (*#2*) will be used to show chart in either header or footer

*Group #2* can be based on same formula as *group #1* (or any other formula/field, it shouldn't matter).

---

Btw, instead of calculating count manually, like in your code

```
    WhileReadingRecords; numbervar cnt := cnt + 1;
```

You can use *Running total fields*, with type of summary *count* on any field you want to control. Such fields are very customizable, so you'd like them.